# How to delete file or directory from root directory of external storage (...removable sdcard root directory)

Tags: java, android, file

i'm building a storage manager app but i can't delete/rename/create
files on external storage

i used `file.delete()` code for internal storage and it's works greate,
but it's not working on external storage files,
also tried

```
DocumentFile fileUri = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
fileUri.delete();
```

and it's dosent work either

how can i write to external storage without using
the `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` each time
the user wants to delete/rename/create file?

- the files path are `/storage/5A85-D438/*files or a folders*`
- already added the folowing permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

including `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Comment: have you added necessary permissions ?

Comment: Please tell full paths of those files. Further it is unclear what you consider to be internal or external. So full paths please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use DocumentFile with createFile on an Output Stream.

```
if (!t.getString("muri", "").equals("")) {

try{
muri = t.getString("muri", "");
Uri treeUri = Uri.parse(muri);

final int takeFlags =
intent.getFlags() & 
(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
this.getContentResolver()
.takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);

DocumentFile mr = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
DocumentFile nf = mr.createFile("text/plain", "JAMZ");

OutputStream os = 
getContentResolver().openOutputStream(nf.getUri());
os.write(pass.getBytes());
os.close(); 

wuri = nf.getUri().toString();
t.edit().putString("wuri", wuri).commit();

} catch (Exception e) {}}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need it for file explorer and i can't request those permission every time the user wants to delete/copy/move/rename a file on his external storage, i need something more paramently...

Comment: It doesnt ask it just writes